# WiredTiger with MongoDb 2.6

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I know that mongo has changed the default storage engine to WiredTiger in version 3, while version 2.6 has MMap.
You can use this to change the default storage engine

```
mongod --storageEngine wiredTiger --dbpath <newWiredTigerDBPath>
```

There are instructions on how to upgrade to 3 and use WiredTiger but I am wondering if it is possible to stay on version 2.6 and use WiredTiger? Is there an equivalent command for version 2.6?

Note: I am not able to upgrade at this time as I am on a shared server which requires version 2.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the WiredTiger storage engine was introduced in v3.0. From the docs (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/core/wiredtiger/) :

> Starting in MongoDB 3.0, the WiredTiger storage engine is available in the 64-bit builds.

In earlier versions such as v2.6, there is only the MMAPv1 storage engine.

Comment: Damn, ok Thanks for your help!